# Why does each Google Apps Script works properly by itself, but only the first Google Apps Script works when I put them both in?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I put only the following Google Apps Script in (by itself), it works properly...

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");             // SHEET NAME
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:C");                  // RANGE TO SORT
 
function onEdit(e)  {
 range.sort([{column: 3, ascending: true}]);        // COLUMN NUMBER TO SORT
}
```

Similarly, when I put only the following Google Apps Script in (by itself), it works properly...

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //Checks to see if we're on Sheet1 or not
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) { //Checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //Checks to see if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

But when I put them both in, the **first** Google Apps Script works properly, but the **second** Google Apps Script fails to work.

What am I doing wrong?

### First, I added the following after I posted my initial question based on feedback I received below

Based on [best practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/155388/hide-unhide-rows-based-on-values-in-particular-cells/155429#155429), I am guessing, perhaps, the combined apps script should look something like this...

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e)
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");             // SHEET NAME
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:C");                  // RANGE TO SORT
     
    function onEdit(e)  {
     range.sort([{column: 3, ascending: true}]);        // COLUMN NUMBER TO SORT
  }
    if (var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //Checks to see if we're on Sheet1 or not
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) { //Checks the column
          var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
          if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //Checks to see if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
            nextCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
      }
}
```

### Second, I added the following after I posted my initial question based on feedback I received below

Based on [best practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/155388/hide-unhide-rows-based-on-values-in-particular-cells/155429#155429), I am guessing, perhaps, the combined apps script should look something like this...

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You can structure the onedit functions to perform multiple functions with logic.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to only have one global function by each name.

If you have multiple copies of a function like `onEdit()` in the *same* script project, only one of them will be active. It does not make a difference whether their argument lists look the same.

See [Which function runs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66906642/13045193) and these `onEdit(e)` [best practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).

Comment: Every function in a project must have a unique name

Comment: Agreed, it is definitely a best practice to not have two global functions by the same name. Unfortunately, repeated function names are valid JavaScript. I do not think you can catch that even with `'use strict';`.

Comment: Please see my feeble attempt at following "best practices" in the code I just appended to my original question.

Comment: Not quite there. See the early part of the [best practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219) post again. Also see [Merging or Combining two onEdit trigger functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62603739/13045193).

Comment: I saw function onEdit(e) {
  doFirstThing_(e);
  doSecondThing_(e);
} but I also read, "You should however consider spreadsheet performance when doing this." therefore I tried the more difficult approach.